# "Could not find property on task set", but task appears in output of "gradlew -q tasks --all"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my Android Studio/gradle build, I'm trying to create a task that `generateDebugAssets` will depend on. If I run:

```
./gradlew -q tasks --all
```

I get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Android tasks
-------------
app:androidDependencies - Displays the Android dependencies of the project.
app:signingReport - Displays the signing info for each variant.
app:sourceSets - Prints out all the source sets defined in this project.

Build tasks
-----------
app:assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages. [app:assembleDebug, app:assembleR
elease]
...
app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
    app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
    app:generateDebugAssets
    app:generateDebugBuildConfig
    app:generateDebugResValues
```

Note `generateDebugAssets` appears in this list.

If I then add the following to `app/build.gradle`:

```
task fooTask() {
}
tasks.generateDebugAssets.dependsOn fooTask
```

gradlew dies with "Could not find property 'generateDebugAssets' on task set."

How do I make `generateDebugAssets` depend on my new task?

Comment: If I try using `preDebugBuild` instead of `generateDebugAssets` I still have the same problem. `preDebugBuild` is shown in the output of `./gradlew -q tasks --all`, but if I try to say `tasks.preDebugBuild.dependsOn fooTask`, gradle complains that it couldn't find `preDebugBuild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/custom-tasks-hooking-on-to-all-flavors-of-a-given-buildtype/7488/8), where Jake Ouellette ran into a similar problem trying to make `compile*` depend on his custom task.

In that same discussion, René Groeschke says "The problem is that the tasks are created in the "project.afterEvaluate" hook." and provides a solution something like this (edited to match the question here):

```
task fooTask() {
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded{ t ->
      if(t.name.equals("generateDebugAssets")){
          t.dependsOn fooTask
      }
}
```

This ensures that the dependency is created after the `generateDebugAssets` task exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task fooTask(dependsOn: 'generateDebugAssets') {

}
```

Comment: I want generateDebugAssets to depend on fooTask, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, you need to check when the task `generateDebugAssets` is added to the tasks collection     `tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if(task.name == "generateDebugAssets") {
        task.dependsOn fooTask
    }
}`